# SQL Server - COUNT with GROUP BY in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been really struggling with this one! Essentially, I have been trying to use COUNT and GROUP BY within a subquery, errors returning more than one value and whole host of errors.

So, I have the following table:

```
start_date  | ID_val     |  DIR   | tsk | status|
-------------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
25-03-2015  |   001      |   U    | 28  |   S    |
27-03-2016  |   003      |   D    | 56  |   S    |
25-03-2015  |   004      |   D    | 56  |   S    |
25-03-2015  |   001      |   U    | 28  |   S    |
16-02-2016  |   002      |   D    | 56  |   S    |
25-03-2015  |   001      |   U    | 28  |   S    |
16-02-2016  |   002      |   D    | 56  |   S    |
16-02-2016  |   005      |   NULL | 03  |   S    |
25-03-2015  |   001      |   U    | 17  |   S    |
16-02-2016  |   002      |   D    | 81  |   S    |
```

Ideally, I need to count the number of times the unique value of ID_val had for example U and 28 or D and 56. and only those combinations.

For example I was hoping to return the below results if its possible:

```
start_date   | ID_val     |  no of times  | status |
-------------+------------+---------------+--------+
25-03-2015  |   001      |      3        |    S   |
27-03-2016  |   003      |      1        |    S   |
25-03-2015  |   004      |      1        |    S   |
25-03-2015  |   002      |      3        |    S   |
```

I've managed to get the no of times on their own, but not be apart of a table with other values (subquery?)

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: `status` change or is always `S` ? what happen if `001` has another `status` what would be the output  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: why do you need a subquery? `select ... group by id_val, dir, status`?

Comment: So, you want one result row per `ID_val`? With `start_date` being the maximum `start_date` for the `ID_val`? And `no of times` being the number of matches of U-28 and D-56 matches for the `ID_val`? And `status` just any status found for the `ID_val`?

Comment: Sorry, yes `status` will always be `S`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes one result per `ID_val` with `MIN (start_date)`. yes that's correct per U-28 or D-56 for each `ID_val`. `Status` will always be `S` for the `ID_val`

Comment: Will there ever be any new value pairs?  Will those value pairs ever change?  If so you're going to need to modify your query or proc every time that happens.  My solution doesn't assume you will always know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one result per `ID_val`, so you'd group by `ID_val`.

You want the minimum start date: `min(start_date)`.

You want any status (as it is always the same): e.g. `min(status)` or `max(status)`.

You want to count matches: `count(case when <match> then 1 end)`.

```
select
  min(start_date) as start_date,
  id_val,
  count(case when (dir = 'U' and tsk = 28) or (dir = 'D' and tsk = 56) then 1 end) 
    as no_of_times,
  min(status) as status
from mytable
group by id_val;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic conditional aggregation:

```
select id_val,
       sum(case when (dir = 'U' and tsk = 28) or (dir = 'D' and tsk = 56)
                then 1 else 0
           end) as NumTimes
from t
group by id_val;
```

I left out the other columns because your question focuses on `id_val`, `dir`, and `tsk`.  The other columns seem unnecessary.

Comment: You may need add some parenthesis for `and -  or`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Maybe for readability, but the logic seems sound without them...?

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select start_date, ID_val, count(ID_Val) as [no. of times], [status]
from your_table_name
where (tsk = 28 and DIR = 'U') or (tsk = 56 and DIR = 'D')
group by start_date, ID_val, [status]
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, all the answers assume you are going to know the value pairs in advance and will require modification if these change or are added to.  This solution makes no assumptions.

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE IDCounts
(
      start_date date
    , ID_val     char(3)
    , DIR        nchar(1)
    , tsk        int
    , status     nchar(1)
)

INSERT IDCounts
VALUES
     ('2015-03-25','001','U'  , 28,'S')
    ,('2016-03-27','003','D'  , 56,'S')
    ,('2015-03-25','004','D'  , 56,'S')
    ,('2015-03-25','001','U'  , 28,'S')
    ,('2016-03-16','002','D'  , 56,'S')
    ,('2015-03-25','001','U'  , 28,'S')
    ,('2016-02-16','002','D'  , 56,'S')
    ,('2016-02-16','005', NULL, 03,'S')
    ,('2015-03-25','001','U'  , 17,'S')
    ,('2016-02-16','002','D'  , 81,'S');
```

**Code**

```
SELECT Distinct i1.start_date, i1.ID_Val, i2.NumOfTimes, i1.status
from IDCounts i1
    JOIN 
    (
        select start_date, ID_val, isnull(DIR,N'')+cast(tsk as nvarchar) ValuePair, count(DIR+cast(tsk as nvarchar)) as NumOfTimes
        from IDCounts
        GROUP BY start_date, ID_val, isnull(DIR,N'')+cast(tsk as nvarchar)
    ) i2 on i2.start_date=i1.start_date
        and i2.ID_val    =i1.ID_val
        and i2.ValuePair =isnull(i1.DIR,N'')+cast(i1.tsk as nvarchar)
order by i1.ID_val, i1.start_date;
```